# Nexus 4 Access Point details

Tags: nexus-4, networking, linux, wifi-hotspot, wpa2

Where can I get details about access point opened by my Nexus 4?

I need them to describe network in **wpa_supplicant.conf** on other device that will be using this network.

```
network={
    ssid="example"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    eap=TLS
    identity="user@example.com"
    ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
    client_cert="/etc/cert/user.pem"
    private_key="/etc/cert/user.prv"
    private_key_passwd="password"
    priority=1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean where is the wpa_supplicant.conf file?

If so, you will need root access as it is in:

```
/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: No. I need info to put in `wpa_supplicant.conf` on my wifi 'client' device .